# fancytree ext-table: how to have a fixed header row

Tags: fancytree

How can I stop the heading row on a fancytree table from scrolling - allowing only the data rows to scroll?

Here's the HTML I'm using.

```
        <div id="scrollParent_history" style="height: 420px; overflow: auto;">
            <table id="lb_tree_bliss_history" class="lb_report_tree">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="175px">
                    <col width="20px">
                    <col width="20px">
                    <col width="20px">
                    <col width="20px">
                    <col width="20px">
                    <col width="20px">
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                  <tr> <th>Date</th> <th>First</th> <th>max</th> <th>Min</th> <th>Final</th> <th>Activities</th> <th>Change</th>  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancytree does not do anything special with the table headers, so you can probably use any existing jQuery fixed table header plugin.

(Note: it may be worth it to check the [project page](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki/ExtensionIndex) every know and then, since this functionality may become a native Fancytrtree extension some time.)

Comment: Thanks @mar10 ... I've now sorted it out. I appreciate your help - I have +1 it but it won't show as I don't have enough rep as yet. Hence this comment.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone I'm using floatThead which works nicely with fancytree 2.21.0. Available on GitHub http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

Add the JavaScript library, then it's a one-liner

```
$('table').floatThead({
    position: 'auto'
});
```